# Resource of python statistics problems and their solutions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, references, descriptive-statistics, scipy

I am learning ML / DS, after learning Pandas, I found a lot of Pandas exercises to practice like this
https://github.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises

Can anyone share such exercises with a solution for Statistics?

Comment: We have a number of posts about resources for learning statistics. Here's a search to get you started. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5breferences%5d%20recommendation

Comment: All these are books and video tutorials, not exercises as I shared in the GitHub repo.

Comment: What’s missing for you from the top hits when you search for things like “Python statistics GitHub”?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Well, I have found a few repos where the learning is not continuous. So I am asking to recommend someone, who might have practiced end-to-end stats using python.